# Change RGB profile to all app globally

Tags: swift, xcode, uicolor

I am developing an app and my designer created his design on Sketch, which for some reason gives different colors than what Xcode gives for the same RGB values. I already understood that since my designer uses his Mac's color profile called `Color LCD`, that it makes sense if I change RGB profile to `Color LCD` and I will get the same colors.. Which worked! but the problem is I can do that only in Storyboard, and I am setting most of my colors programmatically, and I did not find a method to specify that the RGB should be rendered in `Color LCD`. For example:

`let Rackley = UIColor(red:103/255.0, green:135/255.0, blue:163/255.0,  alpha:1)`

This does not give me the color I want.
My most wanted solution would be to set that all the app renders in `Color LCD`. But also a solution that I can take each color declaration in `Color LCD` would do it. Any other solutions would be awesome.